# Unable to record screen sharing in Skype for Business

Tags: multiple-monitors, skype-for-business

My company recently migrated from Lync 2013 to Skype for Business Desktop.  When I record a meeting in Skype, I no longer am able to record any screen sharing.  It worked in Lync 2013.  According to https://support.office.com/en-us/article/record-and-play-back-a-skype-for-business-meeting-6d1dd3c5-ded7-4935-8db0-d6d7173c482f which says:

> When you record a Skype for Business Meeting, you capture audio,
> video, instant messaging (IM), screen sharing, PowerPoint slides,
> whiteboard activity, and polling. Any of the presenters can record a
> meeting and save it on their computers.

I have multiple monitors set up; I tried sharing my primary desktop and tried sharing a specific program on my primary desktop, and neither approach saved the shared screen.  It just recorded audio.

[Update] Additional details originally added as a comment about a month after initial post:

I do have a Targus USB 3.0 ACA038US video driver plugged into my docking station so I can have three screens. Skype recognizes all three screens when I share, but nothing is recorded. I tried sharing just a program and that did not work either. I disabled the monitor using USB video driver and that did not help either. I did not try unplugging the USB adapter yet.

Comment: I found out today I am able to successfully record screen sharing when working from home, where I am not using the Targus USB video driver.  I do have two screens at home; the laptop, and a monitor plugged into the docking station, so the problem appears to be the Targus hardware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out a month after my original post that I am able to successfully record screen sharing when working from home, where I am not using the Targus USB video driver. I do have two screens at home; the laptop, and a monitor plugged into the docking station, so the problem appears to be the Targus hardware or Targus driver.